# Looping through array of booleans to determine which object to include in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, mapping

I have a Javascript question related to **mapping**. So I have *two* arrays...

**Array1**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "analyst"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "reviewer"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "administrator"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "leader"
    }
]
```

**Array2**

```
[ false, false, false, false, false]
```

I want to create a *third* array. So I create a variable and set its initial value to be empty.

```
const roles = [];
```

What I want to do is include the objects in **Array1** into **roles** based on the boolean values in **Array2** in sequential order.

For example, if **Array2** looks like [true, false, true, false, false], then **roles** would be this...

```
roles = [
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "reviewer"
    },
]
```

The reason is because the *first* and *third* boolean values in **Array2** are true, therefore it takes the *first* and *third* objects in **Array1** and puts them into **roles**

I know that *either* .map or .forEach is the solution here, but I don't quite know the best approach.

Can anyone assist?

**UPDATE**

I got this error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'FormArray'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'FormArray'.

const roles = this.listOfRoles.filter((item, index) => this.rolesArray[index]).map((filtered) => ({ id: filtered.id }));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter array one and return value based on array 2 to filter out data like below :-

```
const roles = array1.filter((item, index) => array2[index]);
```

Answer to 2nd query from comment, if you just want to return id :-

```
const roles = array1.filter((item, index) => array2[index]).map((filtered) => ({id: filtered.id}));
```

Comment: That works Aakash! I have a follow up question. What if I wanted to return JUST the ids and not the names? So instead of [
{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "admin"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "reviewer"
    },
] it would be [
{
        "id": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
    }
]

Comment: updated answer for that.

Comment: One final question Aakash, I've updated my question above to include an error I got. I'm using TypeScript in Angular and apparently, it doesn't like the solution. Do you know how to fix that error?

Comment: why you are doing map inside filter callback?

Comment: What do you mean? That's the solution you gave me. I checked it and it works, but the problem is I'm putting this inside a TypeScript application and that's what's giving me the error.

Comment: what is type of rolesArray?

Comment: Aakash, I was able to resolve this by setting the type to any. Thanks!